# how to align search box properly?

Tags: wordpress

I used "Add Search To Menu" plugin to insert a searchbox at the navigation. Now the problem is the box is not aligned well. It is located slightly below the other navigation tabs. How can i align it at equal height among other tabs. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: You need to add the css in custom css. share the link so we can give you the property for same

Comment: thanks! please see above the updated post. i have included the html structure.

Comment: it seems like you are having the width issue. reduce the width of li and reduce the size of font and check the width of ui than and only than this can be in the align

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap only navigation menu in ul tag.(give navigation menu float:left; property)
Make separate tag for the search box. (Give search box div float: left; property)

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to custom css file:

```
#menu-primary li a {
    padding: 0px 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was caused by large number of tabs. After reducing tabs now search is in same row.